# Can i use "Cancel" on part of an instants affect?

Tags: mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2014

Example, happened in MTG 2014 on ps3: I cast Veiled Sentry, comp opponent casts dream fracture, gets to draw his card, but then cancels his dream fracture, stopping me from drawing a card. Im lost because if he countered his counter, wouldnt my enchantment hit the field? Or at the least, wouldnt i still draw a card?

Comment: Can you clarify - did the opponent cast Dream Fracture to counter your Veiled Sentry, and *then* cast Cancel to counter his Dream Fracture? Or did he use Dream Fracture's counterspell to counter itself?

Comment: Dream Fracture can't counter itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Duels of the Planeswalkers follows the rules correctly, no. Cancel targets and counters the entire spell, meaning none of its effects happen. You can't somehow counter one part of the spell and have the rest resolve.

Even casting Dream Fracture and Canceling Veiled Sentry in response wouldn't work (but seems like a more likely bug) as this would counter Dream Fracture on resolution due to not having legal targets.

Comment: I figured if you canceled a spell the whole thing was canceled. Had to be a bug, if so, whatever, i still won :p thanks for answer